# Getting the actual error from dart pattern matching

Tags: flutter, dart

I use a Factory and pattern matching in my model class to convert JSON. But when something goes wrong, I'm unsure how to determine *what* went wrong. I throw the exception, but I can't find any docs to know how that function `_ =>` can give me more info.

```
factory Game.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return switch (json) {
      {
        'id': String id,
        'bggId': String bggId,
        'name': String name,
        'imageUrl': String? imageUrl,
        'description': String description,
        'yearPublished': int yearPublished,
        'minPlayers': int minPlayers,
        'maxPlayers': int maxPlayers
      } =>

        Game(
            id: id,
            bggId: bggId,
            name: name,
            description: description,
            yearPublished: yearPublished,
            minPlayers: minPlayers,
            maxPlayers: maxPlayers,
            imageUrl: imageUrl
        ),
      _ => throw const FormatException('Failed to load Game')
    };
  }
```

Comment: for my catchall, I use something like `final v => throw FormatException('what is $v'),` which ensures it catches everthing uncaught, and thus is exhaustive.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz that's close, but getting invalid constant when trying to do that.